# What is the meaning of "home question"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I have learned what "home truth" and "home thrust" means. But what is the meaning of "home question"?

Answer (score 2):

> **home question**   n. now rare a direct or pointed question, esp. one
>   of a personal nature (cf. sense B. 3).

http://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/87869